# In Node.js and Pug, get the information from a form where items are created dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, forms, express

I am trying to create an application that will have a user create a listing for trade and right now I am stuck on deleting listings when they are selected on a table on a main page. I have a form that I believe will be populated from data from an array passed into the page from a router. However whenever I try to console.log to see if the items are even being passed or data can be received, I get an error page that says the input(selected) that gets passed is undefined. Am I missing something or is this even possible in node.js/express?

Here is the code on the pug page with the form that makes the form and table for the listings

```
mixin getLists(listings)
    each item in listings
        tr
            td.listcell
                   input(type="checkbox" name="selected" value=item.numID)
            td.listcell #{item.name}
            td.listcell #{item.data}

block.content
    .holder
        .listtable
            h4.title Current Listings:
            form(method="post" action="/deleteListings")
                table.listings
                    tr
                        td.listcell
                        td.listcell Name
                        td.listcell Status
                        td.listcell Data
                        +pullinglists(lists)
                input(type="submit" value="Delete Selected Listings")
```

Here is the code from my router for the site that deals with pushing listings to and trying to a dashboard and trying to remove them

```
const express = require('express');
const User = require('../core/user');
const router = express.Router();
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
const user = new User();

var listings = [];

router.get('/dashboard', (req, res, next)=> {
    let user = req.session.user;

    if(user)
    {
        res.render('dashboard', {opp:req.session.opp, name:user.username, listings:listings});
        return;
    }
    res.redirect('/');
});

router.post('/generateListing', (req, res, next)=>{
    if(req.body.name == null)
    {
        res.redirect('/dashboard');
    }
    var temp={name : req.body.name,
        status: "Pending",
        otherData: req.body.data,
        numID: numberID
    };
    numberID++;
    listings.push(temp);
    res.redirect('/dashboard');
});

router.post('/deleteListing', (req, res, next)=>{
    var i;
    console.log(selected.value);
    if(req.body.selected != null)
    {
        for(i=0; i<req.body.selected; i++)
        {
            //remove selected items from the array
        }
    }
    res.render('/dashboard');
});
```

I am somewhat a beginner to node and express so I apologize if there is anything really obvious that I am missing here.

**EDIT**- Thank you MikZuit for pointing me to the correction I needed.

Instead of

```
console.log(selected.value);
```

It should have been

```
console.log(req.body.selected.value);
```

Which then lead me to the following to deleting the form entry

```
if(req.body.selected != null)
{
    var i;
    for(i=0; i<req.body.selected.length; i++)
    {
        var elementToBeDeleted = listings.indexOf(req.body.selected[i]);
        listings.splice(elementToBeDeleted, 1);
    }
}
res.redirect('/dashboard');
```

Answer (score 0):

You have this in the template:

```
form(method="post" action="/deleteListings")
```

So I would expect to see some code starting with this on the server side:

```
router.post('/deleteListings', (req, res, next) => {
```

Otherwise, where would the form be POSTing to?

EDIT: You want to add this in before you call `app.listen`:

```
app.use(express.json())
```

That way you can access `req.body` and get an object with all of the field names and values that you're sending from the form.

You might also need to set `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as the `Content-Type` in your form, I'm not sure what the default is but that's what I use.

Comment: I do have that, but inside of that when debugging I have console.log(req.body.selected); that throws a 500 error and spits out a page that says selected is not defined.

Comment: yes "selected.value" is not defined , "req.body.selected" is, comes from the form

Comment: Look at what I added in the edit, I think it will fix that problem.